# POST Android json data

Tags: java, android, json, http

I'm trying to POST some data to my server, but I don't know why, I always get 400 messages from it.

I want to send this POST structure:

```
POST /api/v0.1/observations/3 HTTP/1.1
Host: 54.154.117.132`
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ 
   "data" : 
   { 
      "field1" : 1111111 
   }, 
   "timestamp": "2015-05-13T12:23:42.648738" 
}
```

If I send that with curl, or wget, I get a 200 Http status.

I'm doing this on android:

```
public void POST(String json) throws MalformedURLException {

    int httpResult;
    //URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.URL));
    URL url = new URL(getString(R.string.URL_test2));
    HttpURLConnection con;

    JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();

    try {
        obj1.put("field1",222);
        obj2.put("data", obj1);
        obj2.put("timestamp", "2015-06-8T12:05:42.648738");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try {
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setUseCaches(false);
        con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        con.setReadTimeout(10000);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", "54.154.117.132");
        con.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        out.write(obj2.toString());
        out.close();

        httpResult = con.getResponseCode();
        Log.i("Request","--> "+httpResult);
        if (httpResult == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) Log.i("HTTP"," --> all ok");
        else Log.i("HTTP", " --> smthg wrong!");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("ERROR"," !!! Interrupcion a la hora de conectarse");
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is exactly the same structure, that's is my conclusion, because using Postman on chrome, and curl or wget, get 200 status.

Someone can help me?

The URL if you want to try is on POST method on the top.

Comment: What happens, if you comment out "con.connect();"

Comment: your json is syntatically wrong

Comment: @JunedAhsan why did you say that? Json is correct, i validate on some sites of internet, if you mean the one on Android code, the name keys or value not necessary to be the same as the POST example on the top.

Comment: @Knossos if comment or removing that line i continue getting 400 message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your params in JSONObject like below:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject .put("field", 222);
        JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            mainObject .put("data",jsonObject);
            mainObject .put("timestamp","2015-05-13T12:23:42.648738");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And change here in code:

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        out.write(mainObject.toString());  //change to mainObject from obj2
        out.close();
```

Comment: yeeees!! that works!! Can you tell me the diference¿?

Comment: See your json string Its have Object inside other object of data and your send all params in one object only

Comment: another question, if I want to send a parameter like "loc" : [1.23, 2.76] how can i do that correctly??

Comment: square brackets are JSONArray you need to send that as JSONArray

Comment: This could be ok?:
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject();
 JSONArray loc = new JSONArray();
 loc.put( (float) 1.233); loc.put( (float) 2.335);
  mainObject.put( "firstname", "Homer J"           ); 
mainObject.put( "surname"  , "Simpson"           );
 mainObject.put( "loc"      , loc                 );

Comment: this: {"firstname":"Homer J","surname":"Simpson","loc":[1.233,2.335]}